# python catching exception

Tags: python, linux

i am running a curl command to check the status of a website:

```
try:
    connectionTest = subprocess.Popen([r"curl --interface xx.xx.xx.xx http://www.yahoo.com"], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    cstdout,cstderr = connectionTest.communicate()
    if cstdout:
        #print cstdout
        status = "OK"
    elif cstderr:
        #print cstderr
        status = "PROBLEM"
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
    print "Error: %s" % e
```

The code works fine except for the try:except statement as its not catching the exception properly, below is the output of the script when the interface is down, now i would like to catch that first line in the except statement... instead it being spawned...is this possible??

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address

PROBLEM
```

Comment: Show us the whole stacktrace. What makes you think there is a problem? If your except clause is not being triggered, there is no exception.

Comment: simply raise an exception if there is a problem in the output of the curl command.

Answer (score 5):

There is no exception thrown.
You can check return code and throw an exception when it is not zero:

```
import sys, subprocess
try:
    connectionTest = subprocess.Popen([r"curl --interface 1.1.1.1 http://www.yahoo.com"], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    cstdout,cstderr = connectionTest.communicate()
    if connectionTest.returncode:
        raise Exception("Curl returned %s"%connectionTest.returncode)
    if cstdout:
        #print cstdout
        status = "OK"
    elif cstderr:
        #print cstderr
        status = "PROBLEM"
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
    print "Error: %s" % e
```

Answer (score 3):

if any exception happens in subprocess, it will not be thrown.
check stderr and raise appropriate exception

```
try:
    connectionTest = subprocess.Popen([r"curl --interface xx.xx.xx.xx http://www.yahoo.com"], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    cstdout,cstderr = connectionTest.communicate()
    if cstdout:
        #print cstdout
        status = "OK"
    elif cstderr:
        #print cstderr
        status = "PROBLEM"
        raise some exception
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
    print "Error: %s" % e
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to call out to curl?

```
import urllib2
try:
    urllib2.urlopen("http://www.yahoo.com")
except urllib2.URLError as err:
    print(err)
except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
    print(err)
```

Secondly, it sounds like your interface address is dodgy, rather than your code. Check the `--interface` flag argument for correctness (ie: **run the curl command outside of python and check that it works as expected.**)

As a general point, you will never be able to catch a child process error inside of your python program (Which is what I think you are asking). You will have to **rely on exit codes** and **stdout/err output**, which is why a solution that relies on Python's [included batteries](http://docs.python.org/library/) will be much more robust.

If you need to specify the interface manually, you have several other options:

1. [PyCurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/):

   ```
   import pycurl
   import StringIO
   c = pycurl.Curl()
   c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://www.python.org/")
   c.setopt(pycurl.CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "eth0")
   # [...]
   try:
       c.perform()
   except: # Handle errors here.
     pass
   ```
2. [Change the source interface manually in python for urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150332/source-interface-with-python-and-urllib2)