# how to change the request ip for a http request?

Tags: python, http, ip, urllib2

I am using urllib2 to send a http request, and the request ip is the machine ip where I send the request. but I want to change the request ip to be another one, what should I do?

```
import urllib2

tmp_url = "http://test.com/load?num=1"
tmp_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; zh-CN; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
tmp_refer = "http://a.test.com/"

tmp_header = {
    'User-Agent' : tmp_agent,
    'Referer' : tmp_refer
} 
tmp_request = urllib2.Request(tmp_url, None, tmp_header)
tmp_result = urllib2.urlopen(tmp_request)
print tmp_result.read()
```

could you give me some suggestion? thank you very much!

Comment: I don't see what you're getting at. What do you mean by 'Request IP'? If you want to send the request to a different server, use a different URL. If you're talking about the address of the machine running your script, then changing the Request IP will result in the response going to a different computer.

Comment: what I say is the latter, and I want to spoofing ip to send a http request, not malicious, I just want to test my program.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150332/source-interface-with-python-and-urllib2) is a quite related question which has been posted on SO and answered by @Alex Martelli. Take a look at this, hope it could give you some hints. :)

Comment: Sorry for not been helpful :(