# Request from different IP addresses

Tags: python

I want to use urllib2 and make a request from different IP addresses.

I have checked this but I am having no luck: [Source interface with Python and urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150332/source-interface-with-python-and-urllib2)

Code from link:

```
class BoundHTTPHandler(urllib2.HTTPHandler):

    def __init__(self, source_address=None, debuglevel=0):
        urllib2.HTTPHandler.__init__(self, debuglevel)
        self.http_class = functools.partial(httplib.HTTPConnection,
                source_address=source_address)

    def http_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(self.http_class, req)

# test
handler = BoundHTTPHandler("192.168.1.1", 0)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com/").read()
```

Error: TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'source_address'

And how would I run this code before using urllib2?

```
import socket
true_socket = socket.socket
def bound_socket(*a, **k):
    sock = true_socket(*a, **k)
    sock.bind((sourceIP, 0))
    return sock
socket.socket = bound_socket
```

So you have the bound_socket function, then what?

**Edit** I don't believe my python version supports the source_address, which is why I'm getting the error, I think.

So, let's try the socket code.

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: here's a [code example that monkey-patches `socket`, and defines custom `HTTPSHandler()` to  support SSL client/server certificates verification for `urllib2` on Python 2.4+](https://gist.github.com/zed/1347055). It shows that you can enable `source_address` for Python 2.4+ (it is simpler than enabling ssl).

Comment: Sebastian is right. What is your python version? In Python 2.6, HTTPConnection doesn't take source_address as argument for __init__()

Answer (score 1):

The code `socket.socket = bound_socket` affects all code that is run *after* it in any module globally i.e., once you run it; you don't need to do anything else.

[`httplib.HTTPConnection` class has `source_address` parameter in Python 2.7](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/httplib.py#l686) therefore your `BoundHTTPHandler` should also work.