# How to send HTTP request using virtual IP address in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, centos

I am using CentOS-Linux and I want to send HTTP requests from virtual IP addresses like eth0:0,eth0:1,eth0:2,etc simultaneously with eth0. How to do this? I am actually tring to make one traffic generator tool using Python. I have been successful in sending multiple and concurrent HTTP requests and now my next step is to send such requests from multiple IP addresses. I dont know how to achieve this task. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to set `ip tunnel`.



[check here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44065/linux-networking-routing-to-virtual-ip-addresses-from-a-different-subnet)

Comment: `eth0:0` is *not* a virtual IP address.

Comment: It sounds like you need [cur-loader](http://curl-loader.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I used following cURL command to send request from eth0:1   " curl--interface 10.91.56.2 http:/10.91.55.3/file0.txt"     and I was successful in generating traffic from virtual eth0:1. Can anyone guide me how to do this using python? 10.91.56.2 is my virtual eth0:1 IP interface and 10.91.55.3 is my server address...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options:

1. use curl:

curl --i <'interface ip using which you want to generate traffic'> destination

eg for me, eth0's ip is 10.91.56.3 and eth0:1's ip is 10.91.56.4 so, to generate traffic using 10.91.56.4(eth0:1)

```
curl --i 10.91.56.4 http://10.91.55.3/filex.txt
```

2. followed answer by @AKX [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150332/source-interface-with-python-and-urllib2)

In above answer in 3rd class write your interface's ip instead of 127.0.0.1
eg in my case i did like this:

```
class BindableHTTPHandler(urllib2.HTTPHandler):
    def http_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(BindableHTTPConnectionFactory('10.91.56.4'), req)
```